# Find files created or modified by an installer

Tags: macos, unix

To track changes in OSX filesystem while an installer runs I'm trying to use the `fs_usage`.
Can somebody guide me with a simple example on how to interpret the result. There a lot of terms I don't understand when I examine it.

Comment: What about using `find ... -user <installer_user>`?

Comment: @fedorqui: OS X installs normally store file as root (or whatever the appropriate owner for the file happens to be), not as the user that ran the install.

Comment: I know, @GordonDavisson. But for instance if you are installing Apache, nevermind the user you are but the new files will belong to new user `apache`. So instead of `<installer_user>` I should have said `<application_user>`.

Answer (score 0):

fs_usage's output tends to be full of irrelevant chatter, and hard to interpret. I'd recommend using [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart), which just shows changed files without all the nonsense. If you're an Apple developer, you can also use PackageMaker's snapshot package feature (which records everything that happens, and offers to make an installer package that does the same things).